# Difference between Kotlin TickerModes

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between Kotlin ticker channel [`TickerMode.FIXED_DELAY` and `TickerMode.FIXED_PERIOD`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-ticker-mode/index.html).  I've played with both, but I'm unable to draw inferences from their behavior.  I've also read the example in the [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/channels.md#ticker-channels).  I would be grateful for a clearer explanation, with an illustration of each.

Comment: This is the same difference as that between [`executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and [`executor.scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). The Javadoc on these methods is quite thorough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can find in [coroutines sources](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/core/kotlinx-coroutines-core/src/channels/TickerChannels.kt) the difference is that `FIXED_PERIOD` is more sophisticated and gets into account the fact the receiver cannot keep up and adjust the delay before next invocations of `send`. This can be tricky to demonstrate though, because you need to measure time a receiver spends waiting for a next tick.

P.S. Note that this functionality is marked as *obsolete*, i.e. *"the design of the corresponding declarations has serious known flaws and they will be redesigned in the future."* In this case the reason is that it isn't integrated with structured concurrency.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("\nFIXED_PERIOD")
    val tickerPeriodMode = ticker(100, 0, mode = TickerMode.FIXED_PERIOD)
    consumer(tickerPeriodMode)

    println("\nFIXED_DELAY")
    val tickerDelayMode = ticker(100, 0, mode = TickerMode.FIXED_DELAY)
    consumer(tickerDelayMode)
}

private suspend fun CoroutineScope.consumer(ticker: ReceiveChannel<Unit>) {
    val job = launch {
        var i = 0
        while (isActive) {
            val waitTime = measureTimeMillis {
                ticker.receive()
            }
            print("[%4d ms]".format(waitTime))

            if (i++ == 1) {
                delay(150)
                println(" adding extra 150ms delay")
            } else
                println(" going ahead")
        }
    }
    delay(1_000L)
    job.cancel()
    ticker.cancel() // indicate that no more elements are needed
}
```

Output

```
FIXED_PERIOD
[   1 ms] going ahead
[  91 ms] adding extra 150ms delay
[   0 ms] going ahead
[  46 ms] going ahead
[ 100 ms] going ahead
[ 102 ms] going ahead
[  98 ms] going ahead
[ 100 ms] going ahead
[  99 ms] going ahead
[ 100 ms] going ahead
[ 100 ms] going ahead

FIXED_DELAY
[   0 ms] going ahead
[ 105 ms] adding extra 150ms delay
[   0 ms] going ahead
[ 101 ms] going ahead
[ 100 ms] going ahead
[ 103 ms] going ahead
[ 103 ms] going ahead
[ 101 ms] going ahead
[ 101 ms] going ahead
[ 105 ms] going ahead
```